# How to make a SpringBootTest treat the autowired instance as a prototype?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, prototype-scope

New to Spring / SpringBoot. I have this interface that represents a toy car dealership:

```java
public interface DealershipService {

  Long getRevenue();

  void sell(Car car);

  void buy(Car car);

  List<Car> findByMake(String make);

  List<Car> findByMakeAndModel(String make, String model);

  List<Car> findByMakeModelAndYear(String make, String model, String year);

  List<Car> findByYearRange(String yearLowInclusive, String yearHighInclusive);

  List<Car> findInCostRange(long costLowInclusive, long costHighInclusive);
}
```

And its implementation, for which only the `buy()` and `sell()` methods are really the only relevant ones:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@Service
public class DealershipServiceImpl implements DealershipService {

  @Value("${revenue}")
  private Long revenue;
  private final CarRepository carRepository;

  @Autowired
  public DealershipServiceImpl(CarRepository carRepository) {
    this.carRepository = carRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void sell(Car car) {
    carRepository.removeFromRepository(car.getVin());
    revenue += car.getCostInUSD();
    log.info("Sold car {}. Current revenue: {}", car, revenue);
  }

  @Override
  public void buy(Car car) {
    if (revenue >= car.getCostInUSD()) {
      carRepository.addToRepository(car);
      revenue -= car.getCostInUSD();
      log.info("Bought car {}. Current revenue: {}", car, revenue);
    } else {
      log.warn("Unable to buy car {}; we're broke!", car);
      throw new InsufficientRevenueException();
    }
  }
.
.
.
```

Buying a car reduces the available revenue, and selling one increases it. The value of `revenue` is at `1_000_000L` (one million USD, supposedly) in my `application.properties` files (under both `main` and `test`).

In trying to test this implementation, I have written the following:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes =  TestConfig.class)
public class DealershipServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private  DealershipService dealershipService;

    @Test
    public void whenNoTransactions_TotalRevenueIsAMil(){
        assertThat(dealershipService.getRevenue(), is(1_000_000L));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenMakingTransactions_revenueIsAffected(){
        Car car = Car.builder().year(2006).vin("1234").costInUSD(10_000L).make("Nissan").model("Sentra").build();
        dealershipService.buy(car);
        assertThat(dealershipService.getRevenue(), is(990_000L));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the action of `whenMakingTransactions_revenueIsAffected()` affects the singleton field `dealershipService` injected into the class. Consequently, when I run all the tests of the class and this test is run first (I don't know why the tests aren't run in the order written), this test succeeds and `whenNoTransactions_TotalRevenueIsAMil()` fails. This is because the revenue falls by 10k and then the first test sees the same singleton instance of `dealershipService`.

This is solved if I make my `DealershipServiceImpl` a prototype bean by adding `@Scope("prototype")`above `DealershipServiceImpl`, but I'm not quite certain that this is good Spring design; there's a reason why Beans are singletons by default.

So I'm looking to find a way to treat the injected `DealershipService` in my test as a prototype *for the purposes of testing*, if at all possible. Effectively, whenever entering a new test, I'd need a new `DealershipService` being injected into the test. Is making my original `DealershipService`a prototype the only possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests are reusing the application context, to make them independent from one another you should use [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-dirtiescontext) annotation:

> `@DirtiesContext` indicates that the underlying Spring
> `ApplicationContext` has been dirtied during the execution of a test
> (that is, the test modified or corrupted it in some manner — for
> example, by changing the state of a singleton bean) and should be
> closed. When an application context is marked as dirty, it is removed
> from the testing framework’s cache and closed. As a consequence, the
> underlying Spring container is rebuilt for any subsequent test that
> requires a context with the same configuration metadata.

For example, you can annotate the test class as follows:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes =  TestConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class DealershipServiceIT {
//..
}
```